# Not able to start Websphere application Server 8.0 in Rational application developer 8

Tags: websphere-8

On the console.. I get the following -

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-jar] [-options] jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -cp -classpath <directories and zip/jar files separated by ;>
              set search path for application classes and resources
    -D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
    -version  print product version
    -version:<value>
        require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -? -help  print this help message
    -X        print help on non-standard options
    -splash:<imagepath>  show splash screen with specified image
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
```

Eventually the server doesn't start and gets stopped after time-out. The Server was working fine. However, I wanted to restart it. I stopped the server completely and tried starting it. Since then I am facing this issue.

Comment: this is `java`'s options / flags. Nothing to do with websphere ( as you tagged ). What is your command exactly?

Comment: I am not using any specific command as such.. I am just trying to start my WAS-8 server on RAD 8..  Simple right-click and start..The server won't start.. All I get in my console is the message I've pasted above..

Answer (score 0):

You can check the script that is getting executed when you right click and start the server.
Check if there are any unwanted entries in the java options which does not confirm to the java command line.

Comment: How will I get to know which script is getting executed? Kindly help